# Can't create request scope beans in Spring IOC using annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, inversion-of-control

I am trying to create a spring application that allows user to register an account. This involves submitting data to a controller which passes data to a service which calls my DAO. This is my first Spring application ever and I have been following a bunch of different guides to get my application where it is.

So my problem arose when I added the request scope to my beans. I added request scope to the service and models beans since the singleton scope was leaving data in my object across different http requests. So when I run my application and send data to my controllers I don't get any console errors, but my application doesn't do anything. When I debugged I 
notice that I get this error when the DAO tries to insert the user object "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.nvc.slink.model.User$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c38e058"
When I looked into my user object when I got this error I noticed that it had weird member variables:

```
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor@5ced77ee
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicUnadvisedInterceptor@40464597
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$SerializableNoOp@21df885d
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$SerializableNoOp@5c608df2
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$AdvisedDispatcher@6b85c397
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$EqualsInterceptor@191d598d
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$HashCodeInterceptor@445db793
```

I'm assuming this is directly related to my addition of the request scope to my beans which also leads me to believe I dun messed up. I have been trying to fix this problem for a week now and feel like i've read every stackoverflow question related to my problem, but with no luck in solving issue.

Here are some relevant source files (I did blot out some of the package names deliberately.)

My configurations:

My java run class.

```
//Application.java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

Hibernate related Beans

```
//HibernateConfig.java
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "xx.xxx.xxxx" })
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public HibernateConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.nvc.slink.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        final HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }


    final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
```

}

Model beans

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;

import com.nvc.slink.model.User;
import com.nvc.slink.model.Userauthentication;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "XX.XXX.XXXX" })
public class ModelConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public User user(){
        Date d = new Date();
        User u = new User();
        u.setULastactive(d);
        return u;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Userauthentication userauthentication(){
        Userauthentication ua = new Userauthentication();
        return ua;
    }
}
```

Service Beans

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;

import com.nvc.slink.service.RegisterServiceImpl;
import com.nvc.slink.service.UserServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "XX.XXX.XXXX" })
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserServiceImpl userService(){
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean 
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public RegisterServiceImpl registerService(){
        return new RegisterServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

DAO beans

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.nvc.slink.dao.RegisterDaoImpl;
import com.nvc.slink.dao.UserDaoImpl;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "XX.XXX.XXXX" })
public class DaoConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDaoImpl userDao(){
        return new UserDaoImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisterDaoImpl registerDao(){
        return new RegisterDaoImpl();
    }
}
```

User Registration Controller

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.nvc.slink.service.IRegisterService;
import com.nvc.slink.transfermodels.UserTO;

@RestController
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private IRegisterService registerService;

    /*
    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/name/{name}")
    public String greeting(@PathVariable String name) {
        return name;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public List<User> index() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }*/

    @RequestMapping(value= "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object register(@Valid @RequestBody UserTO user,BindingResult result){ //Make into register Object
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return result.getAllErrors();
        }
        return registerService.register(user);
    }
}
```

Register Service implementation

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.KeyGenerators;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.nvc.slink.dao.IRegisterDao;
import com.nvc.slink.model.User;
import com.nvc.slink.model.Userauthentication;
import com.nvc.slink.transfermodels.UserTO;
import com.nvc.slink.transfermodels.UserauthenticationTO;

@Service
@Transactional
public class RegisterServiceImpl implements IRegisterService {

    @Autowired
    private IRegisterDao registerDao;

    @Autowired
    private User user;

    @Autowired
    private Userauthentication userauthentication;

    @Override
    public void encryptUA(Userauthentication unencrypted) {
        String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey();
        TextEncryptor encrypter = Encryptors.text("password", salt);
        // TODO Create secure encryption password

        String encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(unencrypted.getUaPassword());
        unencrypted.setUaPassword(encrypted);
        unencrypted.setUaSalt(salt);
    }

    @Override
    public User createNewUser(User u) {
        try {
            registerDao.insertUser(u);
            return u;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User register(UserTO uTO) {
        UserauthenticationTO uaTO = uTO.getUserauthentication();
        userauthentication.setUaPassword(uaTO.getPassword());
        user.setUserauthentication(userauthentication);
        user.setUEmail(uTO.getEmail());
        user.setUUsername(uTO.getUsername());
        this.encryptUA(userauthentication);
        return this.createNewUser(user);
    }

}
```

User Model

```
// Generated Dec 29, 2014 7:43:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

/**
 * User generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "slinkdb", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "u_iduserauthentication"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "u_email"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "u_username") })
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer iduser;
    private Userauthentication userauthentication;
    private String UEmail;
    private String UImgsrc;
    private Date ULastactive;
    private boolean UPrivate = false;
    private String UUsername;
    private Set<UserCode> userCodes = new HashSet<UserCode>(0);
    private Set<UserDefault> userDefaults = new HashSet<UserDefault>(0);
    private Set<Gateway> gateways = new HashSet<Gateway>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String UEmail, boolean UPrivate) {
        this.UEmail = UEmail;
        this.UPrivate = UPrivate;
    }

    public User(Userauthentication userauthentication, String UEmail,
            String UImgsrc, Date ULastactive, boolean UPrivate,
            String UUsername, Set<UserCode> userCodes,
            Set<UserDefault> userDefaults, Set<Gateway> gateways) {
        this.userauthentication = userauthentication;
        this.UEmail = UEmail;
        this.UImgsrc = UImgsrc;
        this.ULastactive = ULastactive;
        this.UPrivate = UPrivate;
        this.UUsername = UUsername;
        this.userCodes = userCodes;
        this.userDefaults = userDefaults;
        this.gateways = gateways;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "iduser", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIduser() {
        return this.iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(Integer iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "u_iduserauthentication", unique = true)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public Userauthentication getUserauthentication() {
        return this.userauthentication;
    }

    public void setUserauthentication(Userauthentication userauthentication) {
        this.userauthentication = userauthentication;
    }

    @Column(name = "u_email", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getUEmail() {
        return this.UEmail;
    }

    public void setUEmail(String UEmail) {
        this.UEmail = UEmail;
    }

    @Column(name = "u_imgsrc", length = 45)
    public String getUImgsrc() {
        return this.UImgsrc;
    }

    public void setUImgsrc(String UImgsrc) {
        this.UImgsrc = UImgsrc;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "u_lastactive", length = 19)
    public Date getULastactive() {
        return this.ULastactive;
    }

    public void setULastactive(Date ULastactive) {
        this.ULastactive = ULastactive;
    }

    @Column(name = "u_private", nullable = false)
    public boolean isUPrivate() {
        return this.UPrivate;
    }

    public void setUPrivate(boolean UPrivate) {
        this.UPrivate = UPrivate;
    }

    @Column(name = "u_username", unique = true, length = 45)
    public String getUUsername() {
        return this.UUsername;
    }

    public void setUUsername(String UUsername) {
        this.UUsername = UUsername;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserCode> getUserCodes() {
        return this.userCodes;
    }

    public void setUserCodes(Set<UserCode> userCodes) {
        this.userCodes = userCodes;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserDefault> getUserDefaults() {
        return this.userDefaults;
    }

    public void setUserDefaults(Set<UserDefault> userDefaults) {
        this.userDefaults = userDefaults;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<Gateway> getGateways() {
        return this.gateways;
    }

    public void setGateways(Set<Gateway> gateways) {
        this.gateways = gateways;
    }

}
```

User DAO

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.nvc.slink.model.User;

@Repository
public class RegisterDaoImpl implements IRegisterDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public User insertUser(User u) throws Exception {
        try{
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.save(u);
            return u;
        }catch(Exception e){ //Could not insert user;
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }   
}
```

Full stack trace added at DAO level where error occurs.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.nvc.slink.model.User$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$332d007d
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.nvc.slink.dao.RegisterDaoImpl.insertUser(RegisterDaoImpl.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.insertUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.nvc.slink.service.RegisterServiceImpl.createNewUser(RegisterServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.nvc.slink.service.RegisterServiceImpl.register(RegisterServiceImpl.java:58)
    at com.nvc.slink.service.RegisterServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8757c338.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.nvc.slink.service.RegisterServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce76b984.register(<generated>)
    at com.nvc.slink.service.RegisterServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8757c338.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.nvc.slink.service.RegisterServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d399c44.register(<generated>)
    at com.nvc.slink.controller.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you give us full stacktrace?

Comment: I added an e.printStackTrace(); in my User DAO, see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are autowiring User entity ( @Autowired private User user ) which is converted to CGLibProxy. Then you want to save such CGLib enhanced proxy to the database and so it fails since Hibernate knows nothing about class User$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$332d007d.

Why are you using User entity in such a way ?

Comment: I've been following a few different guides to put my Spring app. I was following a hibernate integration guide and it autowired the object being inserted into the database. I figured there would need to be a new User object for every request anyway so it made sense to scope it to request and autowire it.

Comment: Try with creating a new one using "new User()" each time please. And see if it helps.

Comment: That would work, but would it be more "proper" to have it created in the IOC?

Comment: No. Entities should not be created using IoC. You should create them manually whenever you need one.

Comment: Okay thanks, so for my current case is it just services that would go in the IoC? or would DAOs also go in too?

Comment: DAOs and other services should be created with Spring IoC. Entites manually - unless you load existing ones from your storage using DAO.